# Using Google Cloud SQL without IP

Tags: google-cloud-sql

It seems that to create users and databases/tables on Google Cloud SQL requires you to

1. download a MySQL client
2. get an instance IP so that you can use the client to connect to the cloud instance

But it shows that to get an IP requires you to pay extra. Is there any way around it?

Can I request an IP for setting up and then remove it later to avoid the charges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add and remove the IP address at any time, and only pay for the charges accrued during the time it was active.

However, unless you are accessing it via a GAE application (which does not need to use the IP) it won't be much use without an IP.

Currently connecting via IPv6 is **free**:

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-client#connect-ipv6

> If you can, we recommend that you connect to your instance over IPv6.
>   Each instance has an IPv6 address that is free to use. To connect over
>   IPv4, you must explicitly assign an IPv4 addresss to your instance,
>   which incurs a charge per hour idle.

Comment: thanks..will do that then. well i plan on letting the application use the db entirely without much maintenance from external apps. they really should have a simple interface for setting up the database for the first time

Comment: Is there a GAE that can create tables in CouldSQL?

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but I can't seem to find how to "add and remove the IP address at any time".  Where is the option to remove the IP?

Answer (score 1):

You are only charged for external IP addresses for instances that are charged 'per use', and then only when they are idle.

Answer (score 0):

The question is outdated.
As of August 2020 public IPv4 for Cloud SQL is free [unless this IP is idle](https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing#sql-storage-networking-prices).

More about idling IP in Cloud SQL in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25249863/google-cloud-sql-idling-ip-address)