# How to un-assign IPv4 address on google cloud sql 2nd gen

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

How to un-assign IPv4 address on google cloud sql 2nd gen?
I tryed use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27475668/7370494), but it doesn't work for 2nd gen sql instance.

Answer (score 0):

Second Generation instances only support IPv4 so it doesn't make a lot of sense to unassign the IPv4 address.